# Git pick changes from another branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches: master, featureA, featureB.
I want to import a few changes(not necessarily in separate commits) from branch A into branch B, how do I do it?
I guess I should use some command in an interactive mode, but I haven't figured out what would do.

Comment: What do you mean "not necessarily in separate commits"? Do you want to import some changes but not others that are part of the same commit?

Comment: Ben, yes, exactly. Imagine I've a huge commit with lots of different changes (for whatever reason), and I only what to merge some of them.

Comment: OK, looks like others are already addressing this.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to use `git cherry-pick`.

You can do this declaratively, by specifying the commit hash to merge in on the command line.

If the changes are not necessarily full commits, `git cherry-pick --no-commit` followed by some editing and a `git commit` (or `git commit --amend`) is what you are after.

Comment: And if the changes are not necessarily full commits, `cherry-pick --no-commit` followed by some editing and a `commit` (or `commit --amend`).

Comment: Will `git merge --no-commit branchA` also work? I care more about the state of branchA, rather than the individual commits it consists of.

Comment: That will work to bring in *all* of the changes, but it won't help you "import a few changes (not necessarily in separate commits)" as per your original question.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Though something like `add -i` would've been more convenient.

Comment: Ouch, I've noticed that it has silently merged all of the none conflicting changes, and that brought me trouble! I want to manually collect all of the changes I want to keep, and not let them slip in by default (like in `add -i`), how do I accomplish it?